# React Virtualized combining custom table and Window Scroller

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I am trying to combine a custom CSS table with the react virtualized window scroller. I currently can get the table to display, but am having trouble figuring out how to combine styling to that table, or add any logic to the table rows.

```js
 <WindowScroller>
    {({ height, isScrolling, onChildScroll, scrollTop }) => (

      <Table
        autoHeight
        width={1000}
        height={700}
        headerHeight={20}
        rowHeight={30}
        isScrolling={isScrolling}
        onScroll={onChildScroll}
        rowCount={table.length}
        scrollTop={scrollTop}
        rowGetter={({ index }) => table[index]}
      >
        <Column
          label='Item1'
          dataKey='item1'
          width={150}
        />
        <Column
          width={200}
          label='item2'
          dataKey='item2'
        />
        <Column
          width={200}
          label='item3'
          dataKey='item3'
        />
        <Column
          width={150}
          label='item4'
          dataKey='item4'
        />
        <Column
          width={200}
          label='item5'
          dataKey='item5'
        />
      </Table>

    )}
  </WindowScroller>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely review the docs. You'll likely be passing both some type of `style` props and `event` props to the components - so you need to understand how those components define and accept those props. This is only possible by reviewing the documentation of the library.

EDIT:

Here are the propTypes for the `<Table />` component:

https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/Table.md

You'll see that it accepts custom event handlers like `onRowClick` but also style props like `rowStyle`

Comment: Is there more documentation then this https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/WindowScroller.md for window scroller?

Comment: yes - see my edit - you don't want to style `<WindowScroller />` itself, you want to style the components inside like the `<Table />` right?

Comment: Christopher is correct. `WindowScroller` doesn't have any presentation layer. It just watches for "scroll" events and passes down `scrollTop` to whatever RV component it wraps. (That's why there aren't many props.)

Comment: Ok I got it working after reading the documentation. Thank you.